# How do I set a default angular select option as the last option?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code. I'm trying to set the default option as the last option in the select box.  If I hardcode the length in the ng-init it works.  `ng-init="mySelect = 3"` But not with `ng-init="mySelect = myData.length-1"`

Any ideas how to set it to the last option?

```
$scope.myData = ['a','b','c'];

<select class="form-control" ng-init="mySelect = myData.length-1" ng-model="mySelect">
    <option ng-repeat="$index in  myData" value="{{ $index }}" >Select This Option #({{ $index+1 }})</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `ng-selected` and the `$index` counter we can conditionally set `ng-selected="true"` for the last option by checking that `$index` is equal to the last index of your `myData` array (`myData.length - 1`). For example:

```
<option ng-selected="{{$index === myData.length - 1}}"></option>
```

Or as @wickY26 pointed out, we can also accomplish this using `$last`:

```
<option ng-selected="$last"></option>
```

You should however take a look at the [`ng-options` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) which is a particular implementation of the `ng-repeat` behaviour but for `<select>` elements:

```
<select 
    class="form-control"
    ng-init="mySelect = myData[myData.length - 1]"
    ng-model="mySelect"
    ng-options="data for data in myData">
</select>
```

Comment: You're right! I've never seen `$last` before. I will update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achive this by using ng-selected in the options attributes.

```
ng-selected="{{$index==myData.length-1}}"
```

Comment: I assume you wanted the model `mySelect` to reflect the fact that the last item is selected, no? This approach (or the above highly-rated approach) would ***not*** achieve that... Just simply assign `mySelect` to be the last item item.

Comment: @NewDev Would love to see a solution if that's the case.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="mySelect" 
 ng-options="item for item in  myData" ng-init="mySelect = myData[myData.length -1]">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Angular (or other MVVM frameworks) is that you could reason it terms of a ViewModel and have the bound View reflect it.

What that means is that if you need something to be selected or some `<input type="checkbox">` preset - just assign the desired state to the ViewModel.

In your case, assign `mySelect` to what you need the ViewModel to be assigned to by default. And the View will follow.

```
$scope.myData = ['a','b','c'];
$scope.mySelect = $scope.myData[$scope.myData.length - 1]; // last value
```

```
<select ng-model="mySelect">
  <option ng-repeat="item in myData" value="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Unrelated to the question, but it's better to use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`, but same idea applies:

```
<select ng-model="mySelect"
        ng-options="item for item in myData">
</select>
```

Just using `ng-selected` doesn't change the underlying model, which is what is ultimately important in an Angular application.